# How to recognize some binary search tree traversal belongs to post-order or in-order?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

If the pre-order of a binary search tree is [P, A, R, S], How to recognize [R, S, A, P] belongs to in-order or post-order?
If is post-order how to find out is (Left, Right, Root) or (Right, Left, Root)?

Comment: Programatically? What about just construct that tree from the input data and then traverse it with `in-`/ `post-` order and get the results? Its `O(n)`

Comment: Can you come up with a code? We can help you with this. `How to recognize [R, S, A, P] belongs to in-order or post-order?`- Build the tree using preorder traversal and Binary search tree property.Then do a inorder and postorder of it and which ever matches with `[R, S, A, P] `, it is that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pre-order traversal is [P, A, R, S], then P must be the root. And since it's a binary search tree, then A must be the left child and R and S must be in the right subtree. That gives you two possible trees:

```
      P                 P
    A   R            A     S
          S              R
```

A reverse post-order traversal of the second tree will provide the sequence [R, S, A, P].

Answer (score 2):

In order of a binary search tree will always be in sorted order. As [R, S, A, P] is not in sorted order, it should be post order.

Comment: Now how to find out is (Left, Right, Root) or (Right, Left, Root)?

Comment: @S.Safari that's now a standard problem you can search.